# Keychron K5SE Bluetooth cannot reconnect after pairing

Tags: bluetooth

Having issues with Keychron K5SEA3. Just bought the keyboard and decided to try it with Ubuntu 20(and 22.04 afterwards... hoping). Problem is - I pair it just fine and it works like a charm. But the moment I decide to disconnect (even changing the channel with Fn+1/2/3) it simply cannot reconnect.

In gnome's bluetooth manager I see the going to Connecting for a fraction of a second, after which it fails. I have tried a few articles which suggested that it needs to be added as Trust, but that doesn't seem to help.

I have other bluetooth peripherals (corsair mouse and sony headphones), which don't seem to have such a problem. Also in Windows the issue doesn't seem to happen.

Help!

Comment: The answer is probably something to do with power management. Essentially, the bluetooth device is exposed to the system on a usb host. Although this really isn't a solution here, I figured you should have a look at it as it is likely the problem. The mouse, headphones, and w/e can work and the keyboard still by itself can be handling the suspend events terribly. I have a keyboard that's fine with it, but my mouse never wakes up. The keyboard and touchpad on the laptop never have a problem.

Comment: @sean, I thought about this, but no - the keyboard can have 3 simultaneous bt connections (triggered by FN+1/2/3). I pair it on the first channel, do FN+2, then back to FN+1, and it cannot reconnect. Matter of seconds.